# Regex: extract float data from String and group it

Tags: java, regex, string

i have a string like this one:

```
288.999,224.004 283.665,258.338 313.332,293.005 312.332,336.671 270.999,389.338 371.998,412.338
```

i try to parse the data to float values, but i want to sort it! The value before comma should by my x value and the value after comma should be the y value.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+.[0-9]*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(pointString);
while(m.find())
{
   System.out.print("x:"+m.group(0)); //x- Values
  // System.out.print("y:"+m.group(1)); //y- Values
}
```

This code just creates a single group...How should i change my String pattern to get a second group with the y-Values...

favored result:

```
x:288.999
y:224.004 
x:283.665
y:258.338 
....
```

Comment: doesn´t work m.group(0) and m.group(1) have the same values!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you are looking for:

```
((?:\\d*\\.\\d+)|(?:\\d+\\.\\d*)) *, *((?:\\d*\\.\\d+)|(?:\\d+\\.\\d*))
```

also, group(0) would bring the whole match, you're rather looking for group(1) and group(2)

Comment: got a "
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )"

Comment: edited, you need to use double "\" when using strings in java

Answer (score 8):

Keep it simple, [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) is enough:

```
String input = "288.999,224.004 283.665,258.338 313.332,293.005 312.332,336.671 270.999,389.338 371.998,412.338";

String[] points = input.split(" ");
for (String point : points) {
  String[] coordinates = point.split(",");
  System.out.println("x:" + coordinates[0]);
  System.out.println("y:" + coordinates[1]);
}
```

Comment: got a OutOfBoundsException: length=1 index=1 for System.out.println("y:" + coordinates[1]);

Comment: check the contents of coordinates[0], seems like ``split(",");`` fails

Comment: if there are also `\n` as a separators, you can use the `input.split("\\s");`

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
 String str = "288.999,224.004 283.665,258.338 313.332,293.005 312.332,336.671 270.999,389.338 371.998,412.338";
    String[] points=str.split(" ");
    String[] point=new String[2];
    for(int i=0;i<points.length;i++){
        point=points[i].split(",");
        System.out.println("X-val: "+point[0]);
        System.out.println("Y-val: "+point[1]);
    }
```